# How to export mysql database structure in csv/excel

Tags: mysql, csv

I want to export the database structure ( not the data ) in tabular format. Is there any tool out  there which can help me with that. Currently I am using MySqlworkbench and it is not allowing me to export without data. My expectation

```
Table_name

Column Name    Type 

column1        int

column2        string
```

etc.

Comment: Are you sure Mysql workbench does not allow that? I think it does but I might be wrong. There is also PhpMyAdmin but I guess you already know about that from your rep. score.

Comment: @Einar Yes, it does allow to export the table schema without data but not in csv. Which I could not figure out.

Comment: This seems like an ugly hack, but could you then import the schema (as sql or whatever format workbench supports) and then export the empty database as csv? I'ts not pretty but it might work.

Comment: I tried the method you suggested and found out that there is no table which was imported.